# For Loops in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop

I am brand new to perl, and I have to write a program that asks for how many numbers there will be and then I have to ask for what the numbers are and then use a for loop to see if the input numbers are divisible by 5 or 6. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

```
print "how many numbers are there?";
$a = <STDIN>;
print "enter your numbers.";
$b = <STDIN>;
for ( $a; $b % 6 == 0 or $b % 5 == 0; ) {
    print "$b";
}
```

Comment: See [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) for more information on for loops..

Comment: *For Loops in Perl* is not a question. What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `$a` and `$b` as variable names, they are special to [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort).

You can use the for loop when asking for the numbers already:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "How many numbers are there? ";
chomp( my $count = <> );

print "Enter the numbers: ";
for (1 .. $count) {
    chomp( my $number = <> );
    print "Divisible.\n" if 0 == $number % 5 || 0 == $number % 6;
}
```

Comment: Oh okay thank you, now is the "my" require for the loop in perl, also the (1..$count) the ".." is used to skip a part of the loop I do not need to fill out correct?

Comment: @Phizy: [my](http://p3rl.org/my) is required under [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict). For `..`, see *Range Operators* in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop). There's no skipping, `1 .. $count` means 1, 2, 3, etc. up to `$count`.

Comment: oh I see, thank you! I will definitely check out that link, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Don't need the `my $i` by the looks of it?